# What libraries have a zoom-to-fit rectangle selector for an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

I'm looking for a Javascript/Jquery library that will allow me to use a rectangle selector on an image (like [this](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/blob/master/demos/tutorial2.html)) and then zoom the selected area to fit the canvas. I've searched everywhere and I can't find anything that matches my description.

The rectangle selector will need to be able to retain a specified aspect ratio as well, but a point in the right direction would help out immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the third example at Jcrop ? 
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/master/demos/tutorial3.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It's close, but not exact. It looks like I'll need to modify this in order to get the exact functionality I need.